# Disable AutoComplete in IE11 via Windows Registry

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, autocomplete, registry

I'm trying to disable Internet Explorer 11 AutoComplete for usernames and passwords on forms using the Windows Registry in a c# application.

The following code works some times *(browser stops asking to save passwords and the checkboxes in AutoComplete Settings is unchecked)*, and fails at other times *(that is, no exceptions but the browser still asks if you want to save passwords, and the checkboxes in AutoComplete settings are checked)*.

**My question:**
Is there another key that controls password saving, or is it perhaps failing due to the user's privileges?  Or am I assigning the wrong value to the subkeys?  Why would it work sometimes and fail silently others?

**Another question:** If a website is running in [compatibility view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567845(v=vs.85).aspx), which displays webpages as if they were viewed by an earlier version of the browser, does IE11 then use the registry keys from the older versions (eg, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AutoComplete`?)

```
// Keys I am manipulating:
// HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FormSuggest Passwords
// HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FormSuggest PW Ask
// others?

RegistryKey regKey1 = default(RegistryKey);
regKey1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", true);
regKey1.SetValue("FormSuggest Passwords", "no", RegistryValueKind.String);
regKey1.Close(); //are these values ok?


RegistryKey regKey2 = default(RegistryKey);
regKey2 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", true);
regKey2.SetValue("FormSuggest PW Ask", "no", RegistryValueKind.String);
regKey2.Close();
```

**Edit:**
I have since discovered several other registry items that appear related to Auto Complete, but it is unclear which version of Internet Explorer these apply to.  It also seems very difficult to find information about IE 11 registry settings in general.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AutoComplete
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel\FormSuggest
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel\FormSuggest Password
```

Comment: is it failing for the same user ? or is it working on development environment and not working on deployment ?

Comment: not the same user, and it works 100% of the time in development environment, but fails *sometimes* in deployment.  I am beginning to think that some of these registry keys require administrative privileges.

Answer (score 2):

Setting access control for the registry key might help to resolve your problem

example

```
 string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
    RegistrySecurity regSecurity = new RegistrySecurity();

    rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user, 
                RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.WriteKey, 
                InheritanceFlags.None, 
                PropagationFlags.None, 
                AccessControlType.Allow));

    RegistryKey regKey1 = null;
            try
            {
                regKey1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", 
                    RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default, rs);                    
                regKey1.SetValue("FormSuggest Passwords", "no",RegistryValueKind.String);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nUnable to read key: {0}", ex);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

These keys are also accessed by Internet Explorer when internet options->autocomplete is loaded:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DomainSuggestion\Enabled
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DomainSuggestion
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Use FormSuggest
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete
```

Seems windows explorer and internet explorer share some autocomplete options.

You can use some registry monitoring tools to see what is being accessed in compatibility view. This is how I found these keys.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and see if this solves it.  It might take a while to test because of the inconsistent nature of this issue.

Comment: Not sure if this answered my question, but thanks for trying.

Comment: There is still an idea: let autocomplete save some passwords, discover where it is stored and leave the program to clean it on reboots. Is that feasible in your case?